# Programa em C : Um certa duvida

Tags: c, portugol

O programa que eu fiz compila, mas o que é pedido não aparece na tela.
A questão é essa:

> Construa um algoritmo em PORTUGOL, que receba três valores, A, B e C, e
>   armazene-os em três variáveis com os seguintes nomes: MAIOR, INTER e MENOR
>   (os nomes correspondem aos valores ordenados).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
  float a,b,c,maior,menor,inter;
  printf("\n Digite o primeiro valor:");
  scanf("%f",&a);
  printf("\n Digite o segundo valor:");
  scanf("%f",&b);
  printf("\n Digite o terceiro valor:");
  scanf("%f",&c);
  if((a<b)&&(a<c))
  {
  menor=a;
  }
  if(b<c)
  {
  inter=b;
  maior=c;
  }
  else
  {
  inter=c;
  maior=b;
  }
  if((b<a)&&(b<c))
  {
  menor=b;
  }
  if(a<c)
  {
  inter=a;
  maior=c;
  }
  else
  {
  inter=c;
  maior=a;
  }
  if((c<a)&&(c<b))
  {
  menor=c;
  }
  if(a<b)
  {
  inter=a;
  maior=b;
  }
  else
  {
  inter=b;
  maior=a;
  }
  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "O que é pedido" é para digitar os valores, isso que não aparece na tela? Ou os resultados? Outra coisa, por que em C se o enunciado perde Portugol?

Comment: Os resultados não aparecem e eu fiz em portugol e rodou no visualg, mas quando passei para C não apareceu resultado algum. Aparece o que é pedido no printf, mas não os resultados.

Comment: É que você define os valores das variáveis, mas em momento algum manda imprimir! Pesquise sobre o comando `printf` do C.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra solução bastante eficiente é utilizando laço For com estruturas de seleção aplicadas dentro do loop, isso também permite que o código fique menor e mais legivel. No final do código utilizei a função printf(), para retornar o valor das variáveis;

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    int main(){
        int i;
        float vetor[3], menor, inter, maior, valVetor;
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            printf("Digite o %dº valor:", i + 1);
            scanf("%f", &vetor[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            valVetor = vetor[i];
            if(i == 0){
                menor = valVetor;
                inter = valVetor;
                maior = valVetor;
            }else{
                if(valVetor > maior){
                    inter = maior;
                    maior = valVetor;
                }else{
                    if(valVetor < menor){
                        inter = menor;
                        menor = valVetor;
                    }else{
                        inter = valVetor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Menor: %.2f\nIntermediario: %.2f\nMaior: %.2f\n", menor, inter, maior);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Há erros em seu código.. Não funciona pra números inseridos em ordem crescente, por exemplo

Comment: Olá, Guilherme! Fiz pequenas alterações no código para a solução deste problema.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução diferente e, mais eficiente para seu programa seria:

```
void main(){
    int a, b, c, MAIOR, INTER, MENOR;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    if(a>b){
        MAIOR = a;
        INTER = a;
        MENOR = b;
    } else {
        MAIOR = b;
        INTER = b;
        MENOR = a;
    }
    if((MAIOR > c)&&(MENOR < c)) INTER = c;
    else{
        if(MAIOR < c) MAIOR = c;
        if(MENOR > c){
            INTER = MENOR;
            MENOR = c;
        }
    }
    printf("MAIOR = %d\nINTER = %d\nMENOR = %d\n\n", MAIOR, INTER, MENOR);
}
```

Não sei se você queria um programa com uma lógica diferente, mas, fazer utilizando diversos if's não é tão prático.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução prática é sempre inserir ordenado os valores.

A ideia aqui é a mesma ideia do `insertion sort`: eu mantenho uma parte ordenada, então adiciono um elemento no final e reordeno o conjunto baseado no novo elemento.

```
float valores[3];
int i, j;
float maior, inter, menor;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  scanf("%f", &valores[i]);
  for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
    if (valores[i] < valores[i-1]) {
      float swp = valores[i];
      valores[i] = valores[i - 1];
      valores[i - 1] = swp;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}
menor = valores[0];
inter = valores[1];
maior = valores[2];
```

As últimas atribuições são feitas e dão o resultado correto porque eu sempre mantenho o vetor `valores` ordenado crescentemente. Essa ordenação se verifica no `for` que vai no intervalo que começa fechado em `i` e termina aberto em `0`, sempre trocando o elemento com seu anterior caso detecte que estão fora de ordem. Como o vetor está sempre previamente ordenado, caso uma dessas verificações não seja verdadeira, então podemos encerrar esse laço interno porque não haverá mais substituições.